# How can I bind click event to custom overlay with Google maps v3 both in IE and Firefox

Tags: google-maps, overlay, clickable

I've already subclass my overlay object under the instruction of google document, and my onAdd() function is listed below:

```
MyOverlay.onAdd() {
    var div_parent = document.createElement("DIV");
    var div_child = document.createElement("DIV");
    div_child.innerHTML = "Click Me";
    div_parent.appendChild( div_child );
    this.getPanes().overlayLayer.appendChild(div_parent);
    var this = that;
    google.maps.event.addDomListener( div_parent, 'click', function(){
        google.maps.event.trigger(that, 'click'); // from [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361823/make-custom-overlay-clickable-google-maps-api-v3]
        alert("Clicked");
    } );

}
```

My code can work well ONLY in IE, but in Firefox and Chrome, the click event will not be triggered anymore.

So how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using overlayLayer mapPanes, you should use overlayMouseTarget.

Reference: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#CustomOverlays

Comment: Is it me, or have they repaired this since? I find that they both work now

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post, but if you were wondering, here is the solution:

In your code above, you need to change the overlay function from:

> this.getPanes().overlayLayer.appendChild(div_parent);

to:

> this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(div_parent);

Answer (score 1):

Also note although your click events will be captured on desktop even if you use overlay pane, for touch events to work, mouse target pane is necessary.