# GMaps create inner link to specific URL

Tags: google-maps, url, redirect, hyperlink

Im using google custom maps v3 include for one of my homepages. im trying to replace the POI-Popups with a link to another site of my blog. F.e. world map is shown, i got layers over each country, if i click on a layer i want to be redirected to a subpage: http://blog.url/subpage/clicked-country.

Is this possible? 
TIA

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: Til now im using a WP Addon, but i think i have to mod it. I found a similar post here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798971/how-can-i-bind-click-event-to-custom-overlay-with-google-maps-v3-both-in-ie-and) - ill look into the addon tomorrow and will post my results here.