# Mouseover on custom overlay in Google Maps

Tags: jquery, events, google-maps-api-3, custom-overlay

Is it possible to listen for a mouseover event on a custom overlay in Google Maps (API v3)? A quick example:

```
function HWPMarker(map, coords, text) { […] }
HWPMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
HWPMarker.prototype.draw = function() { […] }

HWPMarker.prototype.onAdd = function() {

  $(this.getPanes().overlayLayer).append(this.marker); // this.marker is a div

  // THIS IS WHERE I TRY TO LISTEN TO THE MOUSEOVER EVENT
  google.maps.event.addListener(this, 'mouseover', function(){ alert('mouseover') });

}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it not possible to listen for mouseover on a custom overlay?

Comment: is it working or you don't get the alert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7414594/548460) points out that the Maps API v3 doesn't accept mouse events anymore. So what we have to do is to add the DOM element to `overlayMouseTarget` and use a Google Maps DOM listener. This is how it works:

```
HWPMarker.prototype.onAdd = function() {
  this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(this.marker); // this.marker = my dom el
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.marker, 'mouseover', function(){ alert('mouseover') });
}
```