# Make an OverlayView clickable in Google Maps V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to add a mouseover event listener to a Google Maps overlay view. I've been [following this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361823/make-custom-overlay-clickable-google-maps-api-v3), but can't get the listener to work. This is my code:

```
InfoWindow.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView;
InfoWindow.prototype.onAdd = function() {
  this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(this.$content.get(0));
  this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget.parentNode.style.zIndex = 100000;
  google.maps.event.addListener(this, 'mouseover', function() {
    console.log('MOUSEOVER');
  });
};
```

This doesn't give any errors, but also doesn't do anything on mouseover. I've also tried using `this.listeners`:

```
this.listeners = [
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(this, "mouseover", function (e) {
       console.log('MOUSEOVER');
    })
];
```

but it doesn't help either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For the domListener to work, you need to attach it to a dom node:

google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.$content.get(0), "mouseover", function (e) {
       console.log('MOUSEOVER');
    });