# Make GroundOverlay popup tool tip on Google Maps?

Tags: kml

I have this KML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0"> 
<Document> 
<GroundOverlay> 
<Description>ABX_20130830_0009_N0R.gif</Description> 
<Icon> 
<href>http://data.bcinfo3.barrycarter.info/ABX_N0R.png</href> 
</Icon> 
<LatLonBox> 
<north>37.5650361494585</north> 
<south>32.7261689619585</south> 
<east>-104.179216974432</east> 
<west>-109.457981178977</west> 
</LatLonBox> 
</GroundOverlay> 
<Placemark><name>ABX_20130830_0009_N0R.gif</name><Point><coordinates> 
-106.818599076704,35.1456025557085 
</coordinates></Point></Placemark> 
</Document> 
</kml>
```

where "http://data.bcinfo3.barrycarter.info/ABX_N0R.png" has 
a transparent background. It's displayed here:

http://test.bcinfo3.barrycarter.info/bc-image-overlay.pl?center=35.1,-106.54&zoom=13&maptypeid=HYBRID&url=ABX_N0R.kml&refresh=60

When I click on the non-transparent portions of ABX_N0R.png, 
I want it to popup "ABX_20130830_0009_N0R.gif" like I have 
in the  tag above, but it doesn't.

Is there any easy way to make this happen?

I realize I could use another placemark (closer to the 
center of my view), but I'd prefer to have 
"ABX_20130830_0009_N0R.gif" available anywhere on the map.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar before but I accomplished it with a custom overlay type and listening for the click event. Given I had up-voted this answer I think this was the process I followed:

[Make custom overlay clickable (Google Maps API v3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361823/make-custom-overlay-clickable-google-maps-api-v3)

I would think there should be an easier way to just use the standard balloon pop-up like you are asking, but I couldn't find an easy answer searching for you either. I would note the above approach is not too difficult to implement.